# Can I use private APIs for an iPhone Enterprise application?

Tags: ios, enterprise, iphone-privateapi

I'm looking into developing an enterprise iPhone app.  As it will be proprietary and will not be submitted to the App store, am I free to use private APIs?

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure the answer is yes, you can do what you like. Do bear in mind though that private APIs are more likely to break with iPhone OS updates.

Answer (score 0):

There is no app review process for enterprise apps. So the answer is yes. What private API are you thinking of? I'm asking because I'm curious.

Comment: Anyone have some sort of wiki or something documenting the undocumented off-limits api calls?

Comment: An example would be retrieving the user's phone number via NSUserDefaults SBFormattedPhoneNumber.

Comment: Erica Sadun did a class dump of all 3.1.2 frameworks at http://ericasadun.com/iPhoneDocs312/index.html You can browse through there to find interesting bits. I think someone else did the same but then with the option to add comments. Can't find it anymore though.